# revert a file in git and removing it from history

Tags: git

Is there a way to revert a file from a specific commit and also remove from the history that it was ever changed?

For instance, if the file is named `helpme.txt` and the commit was `c5ggjj5`. How can i revert it back to the way it was before the change and have it never show up in the history that it was changed?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
git rebase -i c5ggjj5~
# the first revision should be the one you want to modify
# mark that revision with edit or e
# save and exit
# rebase will start and will stop on that specific revision
git rm --cached helpme.txt #keeping it in the working tree, just in case
git commit --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

And if the file was not touched by any other later revisions, rebase should run without issues. **Warning**: you are rewriting history which has implications.

Comment: Would it not rebase all the files committed?

Comment: Aaahhh.... what? Rebase will reapply all revisions after the one you are modifying so all other files will end up just the way they were (in terms of content and history)... understanding that you are rewriting history.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks for the clarification. :)